# how to process large amount info received by mqtt client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, memcached, mqtt

I have mqtt client to receive the topics and messages like below

```
 client.on('message', function (topic, message) {//this function is executed every 2s
  let msg = message.toString();
  processMessage(message);//this takes long time
})
```

**client.on** will be called every 1 seconds, which is depends on another mqtt-client,who publish the mqtt-message.

**processMessage()** may take around 2 seconds to process(I/O and DB operation)

If I leave it like this, it will cause problems.
Can you guys guide me a correct way to handle this case?

e.g. use MemeCache To fastly cache the data received? 
e.g. use multi-thread?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a burst rate or continuous? If it's continuous then with data coming in at twice the speed it can be processed then it's always going to end up blowing up the system

Answer (score 0):

If you can parallelize the processMessage, then yes, 2 parallel
threads with average processing time of 2 seconds should be able to handle
message arrival rate of 1 / second.

2 second processing time seems long to me, even for I/O and DB operations,
so I would look there first.